# cannot connect to oracle through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I got problem when trying to connect to oracle through Ruby On Rails
`( ruby -r oci8 -e "OCI8.new('hr', 'password').exec('SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY 1') {|r| puts  r.join}"  )` as following:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_re
quire.rb:46:in `require': incompatible library version - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1
.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-msvcrt/oci8lib.so (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:46:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/oci8.rb:20:in
`<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:46:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_
ext/kernel_require.rb:46:in `require'
```

Here is what I am using:

```
 1. ruby1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
 2. Rails 3.2.1
 3. gem 2.0.3
 4. Windows 7
 5. Oracle 10g Express Edition
```

Anyone know how to solve the above problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make sure that the oracle client that you have installed is 32bit.